# How can I configure PyCharm's Python console so that I can run Linux shell commands on Ubuntu 18.04 WSL?

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 subsystem on Windows 10, and I need to use python subprocess library to execute Linux commands. However my PyCharm python console only accepts Microsoft shell commands, even though my python script is in my Ubuntu folder.

Answer (score 0):

Running PyCharm in windows, the subprocess can only run windows cmd commands. However, windows allows several ways to run wsl or bash commands once you have a Linux distro installed.

Either use

```
bash -c [command]
```

Or

```
wsl [command]
```

As your first arguments for the command you want to run in subprocess. You can even specify specific distros to run that command on if you have more than one installed. You can read more of the documentation for it here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-guide-to-invoking-wsl/